# Beautiful Soup data in double curly brackets

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The following is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

r = requests.get('https://pro.eslgaming.com/r6/proleague/standings/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")



table = soup.find('table')

table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

I get the output:

```
[]
['{{team.position}}.', '', '\n {{team.team.name}}\n                        DISQUALIFIED\n', '{{team.points}}', '{{team.matches_played}}', '{{team.matches_won}}', '-', '{{team.matches_draw}}', '-', '{{team.matches_lost}}', '{{team.rounds_won}}', ':', '{{team.rounds_lost}}', '{{team.rounds_won - team.rounds_lost}}']
```

I remember doing some html and remembering that `{{` and `}}` encloses a variable or some code. Instead of printing out `{{team.points}}` could it be possible to get the variable of it, for example `5`.

Comment: Aren't the double curly brackets related to dynamic content generation? Also, I believe it's best to use `BeautifulSoup(r.content, ...)`, instead of `r.text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is actually populated later by Javascript via XHR call. You can inspect those with Chrome Dev Tools.

For example try GET on `https://cdn1.api.esl.tv/v1/teamranking/list?pid=13777,13778,13779&lang=en&`, it will yield nice JSON which you don't even have to parse.

So inspect those internal api calls, or use something which will trigger them like Selenium or Cypress.

Comment: How could I get that link with the statistics for this link? `https://pro.eslgaming.com/r6/proleague/standings/` under the 'apac' section?

Comment: You can open any link having Chrome Dev Console opened on "Network" Tab.